# Setting up the Database on Heroku. bundler: failed to load command: thin , LoadError: cannot load such file -- dm-postgres-adapter

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, sinatra

so I'm trying to do some Sinatra tutorial (JUMP START SINATRA by Darren Jones - https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/jump-start-sinatra)

And it work just fine until deploying the site to heroku when using sqlite database on development mode.

```
configure :development do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
end
```

The problem started to arise when it's time to 'Setting up the Database on Heroku'. Which caused Application error to the site. The error started when adding:

```
configure :production do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end
```

Here's some of the error log from heroku

```
2017-03-07T17:59:07.933651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-07T17:59:07.954951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806844+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: thin (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/thin)
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806948+00:00 app[web.1]: LoadError: cannot load such file -- dm-postgres-adapter
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806950+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `require'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806951+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806952+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in `adapter_class'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806952+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in `new'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806953+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/dm-core-1.2.1/lib/dm-core.rb:230:in `setup'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806954+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/main.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806954+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1411:in `configure'
2017-03-07T17:59:07.806955+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1981:in `block (2 levels) in delegate'
```

Here's the gemfile (copied from the tutorial)

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'slim'
gem 'sass'
gem 'dm-core'
gem 'dm-migrations'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg', :group => :production
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter', :group => :production
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', :group => :development
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.5.0)
      public_suffix (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
    daemons (1.2.4)
    data_objects (0.10.17)
      addressable (~> 2.1)
    dm-core (1.2.1)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)
      data_objects (~> 0.10.6)
      dm-core (~> 1.2.0)
    dm-migrations (1.2.0)
      dm-core (~> 1.2.0)
    dm-postgres-adapter (1.2.0)
      dm-do-adapter (~> 1.2.0)
      do_postgres (~> 0.10.6)
    dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)
      dm-do-adapter (~> 1.2.0)
      do_sqlite3 (~> 0.10.6)
    do_postgres (0.10.17)
      data_objects (= 0.10.17)
    do_sqlite3 (0.10.17)
      data_objects (= 0.10.17)
    eventmachine (1.2.3)
    pg (0.19.0)
    public_suffix (2.0.5)
    rack (1.6.5)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    sass (3.4.23)
    sinatra (1.4.8)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slim (3.0.7)
      temple (~> 0.7.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    temple (0.7.7)
    thin (1.7.0)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1, < 3)
    tilt (2.0.6)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  dm-core
  dm-migrations
  dm-postgres-adapter
  dm-sqlite-adapter
  pg
  sass
  sinatra
  slim
  thin

BUNDLED WITH
   1.14.3
```

Anyone know how to fix this..? Have tried searching for answers at stackoverflow. But couldn't find anything that works.

I'm a total newbie at programming, and English is not even my first language. So please forgive me if there's any weird or wrong words in my question.

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: could you post your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Sure, adding Gemfile.lock to the question